# Jupyter Notebook with Matlab kernel

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.x, jupyter

I basically have a bunch of user-defined functions that I can run when I use Matlab, because I can specify the working directory. However when I use Jupyter Notebook those functions are undefined. How do I specify the working directory in this case?

Either a permanent solution or a session solution is OK. However my preference is the session solution, so that I do not have to specify back the working directory all the time to its default value.

Comment: Use addpath maybe?

Comment: that worked! perfect

Comment: I posted a more complete answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function [`addpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) to add a directory containing M-files to the MATLAB search path.

Some relevant links to documentation pages:

- [What Is the MATLAB Search Path?](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html)
- [Files and Folders that MATLAB Accesses](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/files-and-folders-that-matlab-accesses.html)
- [Add Folders to Search Path Upon Startup](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/add-folders-to-search-path-upon-startup-on-unix-or-macintosh.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing the functions, you can use bash script inside Jupyter notebook. This way you can have your functions in front of you. With the example code below, they will be written down on the same path. But you can save them anywhere at the end, again using `%%shell`.

```
%%shell
echo "
y = func(x) ... % here you copy the function m file
" > func.m
```

Also you can implement the Amro's answer inside the notebook with `%%shell`. This way you can have a session solution within the Jupyter notebook.